# Type not found error (missing using directive or assembly reference?) with Ninject

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, ninject

One class in my console app made using Ninject (Ninject-2.2.0.0-release-net-4.0) in .NET Framework 4.0 looks like this:

```
…
using Ninject;

namespace IoC
{
    class IoC
    {
        private IWriter _writer;
        public IWriter Writer { get { return _writer; } }

        [Inject]
        public IoC(IWriter writer)
        {
            _writer = writer;
        }
    }
}
```

When I build the solution it gives me the following error:

> *The type or namespace name 'Ninject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

And lots of such kind of asssembly not found errors for ninject.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Well, *have* you added a reference for the Ninject assembly to your project, as the error message suggests?

Answer (score 2):

You must have downloaded the web version of Ninject. Use the [non-web version](http://github.com/downloads/ninject/ninject/Ninject-2.2.0.0-release-net-4.0-no-web.zip).

Edit:

Technically, you should be able to use the web version in a console application. You just need need to change the target framework from ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".NET Framework 4" since Ninject requires a reference to System.Web.

Comment: Let me Explain my problem more deeply,When I add reference of Ninject.dll and Then writing using Ninject its working fine but as soon as I build My Solution and Then the above error generates for Ninject Namespace can you answer me thanks

Comment: Your sample code works fines in my solution. How did you add the reference? Do you see any more errors or warnings?